# Wordpress plugin to create custom fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a wordpress site for local music events (the mvp from a non-tech fouder). I am looking for a wordpress plugin which will let me create custom fields and tags to add multi-day music events. A typical event may be 3-6 days long and will have information like:

Event name,
Day wise s,hedule,
Music Genre,
Bands,
Band Members,
Venue,
city,
Book Ticket button,

Any plugin/theme recommendation will highly appreciated as this will let me get with my customer validation really quickly.

Thanks
Brandon

Answer (score 2):

Try Advanced Custom Fields. I use it all the time and it's awesome. 1 million + downloads and almost a 5 star rating.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Events Manager Pro (http://eventsmanagerpro.com/) is a very robust events calendar that supports multi-day events. It uses custom post types for the events and it's easy to extend it -- the plugin has pretty extensive hooks and filters available and decent API documentation. I use it on a number of projects.